# Infinite scrolling within a tabbed listview on Android

Tags: mobile, android, user-research, user-expectation, tabs

Is it a good experience to give an infinite scrolling view across tabs in Android if there are tabbed list views in the app?

Basically if a user scrolls through a list in a tabbed view, the tab auto scrolls to the next tab once the user reaches the end of the list in one tab. Also if the users scrolls back on the list, he's taken to the previous tab (so like an infinite scrolling list across tabs).

I see an implementation on iOS of a similar kind in this app. 
https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/grofers-local-shopping/id960335206?mt=8

Will this make sense on Android?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure the use case for this. what are the tabs? what does the app do?

I think perhaps there is a way to prompt your users to move to the next tab without auto-moving to the it.

The issue is it's an action that the user can not undo, if i'm scrolled at the bottom of a long list, then auto moved to another list...i just lost my place. Also it's not a common pattern users are familiar with. Plus having the a tab bar means that the next tab is only a tap away and always visible.

Comment: Think of the app as basically as a list of news articles split by tabs which are categories. So tabs might be "Featured", "Sports","Current affairs" and so on, each having a list of articles. Once I reach the end of Featured tab, it auto scrolls into Current affairs etc.,

Answer (score 0):

Infinite scrolling + swipe between tabs is a great idea.
What you have to be aware of is respecting the patterns of each OS. As an example, remember iOS has the tab bar on the lower of the screen while Android uses it on top of the navigation bar. Also, the back button for android should take the user to the last tab visited but in iOS you won't have a behaviour such as this one. Keep your patterns clear and solid while using interactions which are new for you users. And of course test them to proove users understand them and find it useful.

Swarm is a good example of many differences iOS and Android have.

[image]

Comment: Infinite scrolling amongst tabs also? i.e. If I reach the end of the list in one tab, the tabs change ?